# Flash AS3 copyPixels from BitmapData into jpeg screenshot

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, screenshot

I have code to create a live screenshot of the stage in my swf.
After that it saves as a jpeg. All good.

Only, I don't need the whole stage, I only need a cutout:

x,y: 357,341
widt,height: 319,483

My code looks like this..

Where and how do I insert the copypixels function?

(I'm a Flash novice, so go easy on me :-)

```
function mouseReleaseSave(event:MouseEvent):void {
import com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequestHeader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

var jpgSource:BitmapData = new BitmapData(this.stage.stageWidth, this.stage.stageHeight);
jpgSource.draw(this.stage);
var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(70);
var jpgStream:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(jpgSource);

//set the request's header,method and data
var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type","application/octet-stream");
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
//sends jpg bytes to saveJPG.php script
var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("saveJPG.php");
myRequest.requestHeaders.push(header);
myRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
myRequest.data = jpgStream;
loader.load(myRequest);
//fire complete event;
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,saved);
function saved(e:Event){
    //trace the image file name
    trace(loader.data);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:

```
var subArea:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0, 319,483 );
var newBmp:Bitmap = new BitmapData( 319,483 );
var cutoutBmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap( newBmp, PixelSnapping.ALWAYS, true );
cutoutBmp.bitmapData.draw( jpgSource, new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -357, -341) , null, null, subArea, true );
```

Comment: When trying to use the answer from protozoo, I get: "1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type flash.display:BitmapData to an unrelated type flash.display:Bitmap." - am I missing something?